# A variable contributes less to R2 value in the multiple regression model than alone in the linear regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I would like to ask a basic question. A multiple regression model, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, has R2 value of 0.152. Now I have a new variable z, and its linear regression model, y ~ z, has R2 value of 0.051. However, when I put z in the multiple regression model, y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + z, then R2 value is 0.153. Why is it not 0.152 + 0.051?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $R^2$ is the percent of variability in $y$ that is explained by your independent variables.  Based on your data, this means that $z$ on its own explains about $5.1\%$ of the variability in $y$ but that it only explains $0.01\%$ of the variability in $y$ once $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ have already been taken into account.

Depending on the statistical software you use, this *might* be different.  It will depend on which "sums of squares" each software uses.  R, for example, uses sequential sums of squares, which means that the first independent variable $x_1$ in will explain some of that variability in $y$, then the next independent variable $x_2$ may explain some more variability in $y$ or it might not once $x_1$ is already taken into account.  Thus the $R^2$ when adding in a new variable $z$ will not necessarily increase by the same $R^2$ value when you merely regress $y$ on $z$.

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you very much for your answer. Does it make sense to think that  (5.1 - 0.01)% of the variability is explained by the other predictor variable(s) when z is added into the model where x1, x2 and x3 are already present?

Comment: That's correct. We don't know how much is explained by x1, x2, or x3 individually without more analysis, but they jointly explain about 5.09% of the variability in y.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this effect is due to the fact that $z$ is correlated with one or more of the other explanatory variables. In other words, once you're already taking the other variables into account, only the component of $z$ which is orthogonal to all of the other variables contributes to explaining variability in $y$.

OP, please accept the answer provided by @MattBrems if you find it acceptable.